# Can I prevent the need to pass this into inherited function as a parameter?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Base class 1:

```
class CBaseEditor
{
public:
    bool CBaseEditor::ImportTemplate(CWnd* pParent)
    {
        CFileDialog dlgImport(TRUE,
        _T(".XSL"), _T(""), 
        OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, 
        _T("FilterText"), pParent);
   }
}
```

Base class 2:

```
class CResizingDialog : public CDialogEx
{

}
```

Dialog class, derived from both bases:

```
class CFieldServiceGroupReportDlg : public CResizingDialog, public CBaseEditor
{
    private:
    void SuneFunc()
    {
        ImportTemplate(this);
    }
}
```

My `ImportTemplate` function, is there anyway for it to get access to the "this" from the caller without having to pass "this" in?

---

Based on the comment provided I have come to the conclusion that the best thing to do is change my existing constructor (field class has since been renamed):

```
CPublishersDatabaseViewerDlg::CPublishersDatabaseViewerDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CResizingDialog(L"GroupsReport", IDD_DIALOG_PUBLISHERS_DATABASE_VIEWER, pParent)
    , m_strPreviewXSL(L"")
{
    m_strPreviewXSL = theApp.GetStringSetting(L"Options", L"PublisherDB_Style", L"PublisherDB--Field Service Groups");

}
```

By design the dialog class accepts a parent. Likewise, I should change `CBaseEditor` to accept an appropriate parent in some way. Than I won't need to pass it all the time. This is my base constructors:

```
CResizingDialog::CResizingDialog(const CString& strWindowID, UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent /* nullptr */, bool bOnlyStorePosition /* false */)
    : CDialogEx(nIDTemplate, pParent)
    , m_bDoNotShowResizeIcon(false)
    , m_bOnlyStorePosition(bOnlyStorePosition)
    , m_bLimitToHorizontalResizing(false)
    , m_strWindowID(strWindowID)
{
    m_rcInit.SetRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

CBaseEditor::CBaseEditor() noexcept(false)
{
    Init();
}
```

Comment: No, if I understand correctly. Because you have 2 base classes, only one of the base classes can be `CWnd` or `CDialog`. In `CFieldServiceGroupReportDlg` you have one `m_hWnd` which sits in `CResizingDialog`. The `m_hWnd` (or `this`) has to be passed to `CBaseEditor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

Change my dialog constructor to feed in the `this` to the `CBaseEditor`:

```
CPublishersDatabaseViewerDlg::CPublishersDatabaseViewerDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/) noexcept(false)
    : CResizingDialog(L"GroupsReport", IDD_DIALOG_PUBLISHERS_DATABASE_VIEWER, pParent)
    , CBaseEditor(this)
    , m_strPreviewXSL(L"")
{
    m_strPreviewXSL = theApp.GetStringSetting(L"Options", L"PublisherDB_Style", L"PublisherDB--Field Service Groups");

}
```

### Step 2

Add a new `CWnd*` variable to the base editor and update the constructor:

```
CBaseEditor::CBaseEditor(CWnd* pParent /* nullptr */) noexcept(false)
{
    m_pParentWnd = pParent;

    Init();
}
```

### Step 3

Change the `ImportTemplate` function as it no longer needs the parent passed in. We can use the `m_pParentWnd` instead.

Comment: That's the right way. The only drawback is that this code may get too complicated to follow because of the additional dependencies.